# Add Alt keyboard shortcuts to TextFX menus in Notepad++

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, notepad++, plugins

Is there a way to add <kbd>Alt</kbd> keyboard shortcuts (usually shown as an underlined letter e.g. F̲ile > S̲ave) to the TextFX menus in Notepad++ 5.8.6 (the last version before the huge ugly Find dialog)?

As I prefer to leave my hands on the keyboard instead of reaching for the mouse, to use the menus, I currently need to press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> then use the cursor keys or press <kbd>T</kbd> multiple times to navigate to the relevant item.

I know that I can bind keys to specific items, but don't use any individual item often enough to devote a whole set of shortcuts to them. Additionally, I would need to remember what the bindings are, whereas the underlined letters serve as a clear reminder.

I found that adding an ampersand before a character in the localization XML file makes it an <kbd>Alt</kbd> shortcut, but TextFX is obviously not in these files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using HEX-Editor plugin, search in ANSI mode for

> Viz S

and add ampersands before letters to make shortcut (strings are null-padded, so you can use extend the length of the string by similarly reducing the nulls after it).

To change "TextFX Characters" menu label, search in hexadecimal mode for

> 43 00 68 00 61 00 72 00 61 00 63 00 74 00 65 00 72 00 73

and modify non-zero characters. As this string cannot be extended, you could "annex" a character from another part of the string, say, the "s" to make "TextFX &Character".

Comment: You *can* modify non-zero characters as long as there is at least one at the end. It represents the "end of string" byte. I've found most of the strings in `NPPTextFX.dll` have plenty of null characters to allow for the addition of the `&` in the menu.

Answer (score 3):

I found another way ... let me know how this works for you.

In the file menu Macro > Modify Shortcut/Delete Macro ...

Choose the plugins Tab, select a Text FX command that you want to assign a shortcut to.

Finally check your results in the TextFX menu

I had screenshots, but it would not let me post images since my rep is low.

Comment: Thanks and welcome to Superuser :-) That would work, but requires dedicating many shortcut keys to the many TextFX commands -- and is quite tedious!